# Can you create a new folder using the Autodesk Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-data-management

I'm looking for a way to create a new folder under an existing A360 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this feature is not yet available. (as of August/2016)

Comment: Augusto,

Is there a timeframe for adding this feature, and are there any plans to add the ability to delete an item or a folder?

Thanks

-Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk provided an API that does the job:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-POST/